# Wrap the text in dataList of primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

```
 <p:dataList value="#{testBean.students}" var="stud" rows="5" >
        <p:column>  
            <p:commandLink value="#{stud.name}" action="#{testBean.edit}" process="@this">    
            </p:commandLink>  
        </p:column>
  </p:dataList>
```

I am using simple data list and used command Link to edit.This data list is a list of students.

> My question is  datlist has student name with
>   "teststudent1234567890123456789012345678901234567890".

How do i wrap this name in a datalist so that I can display only teststudent and wrap word so that it can fit in datalist. Validation is done and student name can have a maximum of 50 character.

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to, if having such name, why do you want to display only the first part?

Comment: @Xtreme biker: I am trying to display the name as it is, But when length of character in mare than 10, alignment issues are there in a datalist. so in order to dispaly the whole name,I have decided to wrap a word.

Comment: @XtremeBiker: Can you please suggest me how do I display this name in dataList.I have the name with more than 10 character.

Comment: Use `#{fn:substring(name, begin, end)}` like that `#{fn:substring(stud.name, 0, 10)}`. Don't forget to include the namespace in your view in order to make jstl functions available for your page: `xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `#{fn:substring(name, begin, end)}` like that `#{fn:substring(stud.name, 0, 10)}`. Don't forget to include the namespace in your view in order to make jstl functions available for your page: `xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"`. [Here you have an example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_function_substring.htm) and also [the specification of jstl 1.1 functions](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/tld-summary.html).